# Wiring an optocoupler to have both inverting and non-inverting output

Tags: transistors, opto-isolator

Can an optocoupler be wired to give both inverting and non-inverting logic output without additional active components?

I'd like to avoid using an inverter if possible, but also curious as to whether this is trivially possible.

Suppose I am talking about a normal [PC817](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1760298.pdf) with phototransistor output.
Also I want both outputs to be isolated.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid extra components?

Comment: You could add both (or either) a collector and emitter resistor, resulting in a symmetric output, but I'm unsure how that changes rsponse characteristics.

Comment: I am using 24V logic, and my supplier doesn't seem to have such inverters, also one less entry in the BOM.

Comment: A single transistor and one or two resistors make an inverter that easily copes for 24V.

Comment: @jippie probably thats what I'll resort to, but I am an amateur, so I rather asked to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm9HWb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Inverted signals from single opto-isolator. Note that outputs do not cross and are unlikely to switch any standard logic properly.*

Comment: This is a pull-up/pull-down resistor approach.  The resistor needs to be sized relative to the load/input impedance. http://www.resistorguide.com/pull-up-resistor_pull-down-resistor/

Comment: This is a pull-up/pull-down resistor approach. The resistor needs to be sized 10 times smaller than the value of the input pin impedance.  1K is probably a good universal value, but I often see 2.7K used instead. http://www.resistorguide.com/pull-up-resistor_pull-down-resistor/

Answer (score 4):

If you want full logic swing 0-24V signals then it will be necessary to add one more transistor and a couple of resistors like this:

[image]

Comment: This is the approach I will take, but I have accepted transistor's answer, because I asked about not using actives. Still great answer.

Comment: I believe that in relation to LED current your outputs are marked inversely.

Answer (score 1):

Another option with near identical response times between the channels (at the cost of extra components) and both channels near full swing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFbaSq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>